# Probability of Unfair coin with p between (0, 1) and find # of heads s.t. it is even or |3.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

An unfair coin has a probability p of showing heads of between 0 and 1 (0, 1) is tossed n times. What's the probability that total count of heads is even? divisible by 3?

If it is a fair coin, then for a) even, it is probability of $$
\left(\frac{\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+...+\binom{n}{2*int(n/2)}}{2^n}\right)$$

but how does p ∈ (0, 1) change this problem? thanks

Comment: I noticed that you have a disturbing tendency to not choose a best answer to any of your questions (except one). A lot of your questions had good answers. Once you receive satisfactory answers to your questions, you should choose the best one. If you are not satisfied with the answers, ask for clarifications.

Comment: my bad i will from now on

Comment: i do upvote tho so why is that considered "disturbing"?

Comment: Once your questions are answered to your satisfaction, it is best to select a best one to get them off the "Unanswered" tab. Otherwise, people who browse through that tab might waste their time looking at a question that has already been answered well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of heads even is:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}(1-p)^{n-2i} &= \binom{n}{0} (1-p)^n+\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2} + ... + \binom{n}{2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} p^{2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}(1-p)^{n - 2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
\end{align}

The denominator of $2^n$ is only valid when the coin is fair since $p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$.

You can find the explicit value of this sum as follows:
$$1^n = (p+(1-p))^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i}$$
$$((1-p)-p)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i}p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i}$$
If we add these two sums together the odd terms will cancel, so we get:
$$1+(1-2p)^n = 2\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}(1-p)^{n-2i}$$
Hence, the probability of heads even is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}(1-p)^{n-2i} = \frac{1}{2}(1+(1-2p)^n)$$

---

The probability that the total number of heads is divisible by three is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\binom{n}{3i}p^{3i}(1-p)^{n-3i} = \binom{n}{0}(1-p)^n+\binom{n}{3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}+...+\binom{n}{3\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}p^{3\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}(1-p)^{n-{3\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}}$$
It is slightly trickier to get the (quite ugly) closed form for this one.

Comment: please explain the meaning of p ∈ (0, 1) does it mean p can be an element of any value between 0 to 1 not including 0/1? my biggest question is how do you come up with the explicit value of this sum? that was a smart step but please explain how you thought of that

Comment: @jamesblack $p\in(0,1)$ means that $0<p<1$. Do you know the binomial theorem? Once you know that, it is not hard to find a way to get the odd terms in the binomial expansion to cancel out.

Comment: i do but ill look further into that thanks